# NextAuth mongodb Adapter no manda la informacion del usuario a la db

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, nextjs, next

Estoy aprendiendo sobre nextjs y una de las cosas que me gusto fue la posibilidad de usar Next-Auth y poder mandar la informacion del usuario a una base de datos usando los adapters que ofrece.
En mi proyecto tengo la estructura basica del adapter que esta en esta pagina(https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/mongodb)pero ya probe de todo y no logro hacer que funcione.

A continuacion muestro todo el codigo por si ven algo que yo no xd

/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].tsx

```
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github"
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter"
import clientPromise from "./lib/mongodb"

export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

/pages/api/auth/lib/mongodb.tsx

```
// This approach is taken from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) { 
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;
```

!global._mongoClientPromise me arroja error en "_mongoClientPromise" pero creo que no se debe a esto el error que tengo
Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.

La variable de entorno para la conexion es: MONGODB_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/app (Ya probe con localhost y otras formas). Con LOCALHOST en consola me tira error de conexion por lo que tengo entendido la conexion con la base de datos funciona. Lo que no estaria funcionando es el push hacia la database.

Tambien probe usando una base de datos mongo atlas y cambiando la extension de los archivos a js y ts

Si necesitan algun otro archivo pidanlo que estoy activo porque hace semanas tengo este error :)
Un saludito

Comment: Los datos del usuario se guardan perfectamente en las cookies del navegador, no se  porque no funciona aaaaaa :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El adapter no va adentro de tu proveedor. El adapter es una llave en las opciones al mismo nivel que `providers`.

```js
providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
```

Puedes referenciarte en [los docs](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/mongodb).